# how to retrieve data from database in servlet

Tags: java, crud, servlet-3.0

im beginners in java servlet... i working on curd operation... 
 ...data not displaying please tell me where im wrong....

DAO.java

```
public void select(){

        try{
            Class.forName(jdbcDriver);
            Connection conn = DriverManager .getConnection(connectionString,username,password);
        PreparedStatement create = conn.prepareStatement("select * from student.users");

            ResultSet rs;
            rs = create.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                int id =rs.getInt("id");
                String name = rs.getString("fname");

            }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

servlet.java

```
DAO user = new DAO();   /// i create object of DAO
user.select();  //calling select method

out.write("<td>");
                    out.write("<p>"+user.id+"</p>");    ///tried many from different way
            out.write("</td>");
            out.write("<td>"); 
                    out.write("<p>"+user.name+"</p>");    ///
            out.write("</td>");
```

i tried many from different way but no luck....  can you tell me where I'm wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some problems there.
First i think your select method should return a List of users.
So you can implement that as bellow

```
public List<User> select(){
    List<User> result = new ArrayList<User>();
    try{
        Class.forName(jdbcDriver);
        Connection conn = DriverManager .getConnection(connectionString,username,password);
    PreparedStatement create = conn.prepareStatement("select * from student.users");

        ResultSet rs;
        rs = create.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            int id =rs.getInt("id");
            String name = rs.getString("fname");
            User user = new User(); // Creating a user object to fill with user data (I imagine that you have a user class in your model)
            user.setId(id);
            user.setName(name);
            //Add the retrived user to the list
            result.add(user);

        }
        //Returning the list of users.
        return result;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

So in your servlet you can call this method to return this list
and show it.

```
 DAO daoUser = new DAO();   /// i create object of DAO
 List<User> users = daoUser.select();  //calling select to get list of users
 out.write("<table>");
 for(User user : users){ //Running through the list to show all users retrived
    out.write("<td>");
    out.write("<p>"+user.id+"</p>");    
    out.write("</td>");
    out.write("<td>"); 
    out.write("<p>"+user.name+"</p>");    ///
    out.write("</td>");
 }
 out.write("</table>");
```

So that's it.
The logic it's that i'm not sure if it will work, may a forget some detail but this is the way to do. 
Hope that helps.